# Entity Framework query is super slow

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am reading records from a Log table. The table currently has 260,000 records with 8 columns. This is the code via EF6.

```
using (var ctx = new DbEntities())
{
    ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var k = ctx.Logs.Where(l => l.ApplicationId == id && l.Level <= 3 && (l.Dat == 20160514 ||l.Dat == 20160513 ) ).ToList();
    sw.Stop();
}
```

The above take 7-8 seconds to return 2213 rows. Running the equivalent on SSMS tales less than a second.

I have tried also running the query as

```
ctx.Logs.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Log WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE ApplicationId = 4 and Level <= 3 and (Dat = 20160513 or Dat = 20160514)").AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

This also takes ~7 seconds

I have 2 non-clustered keys one which is just ApplicationId DESC and the other is ApplicationId DESC, Dat DESC, Level ASC.

Activity monitor never shows load on the database.

This seems like a long time for a query of this size. Or are my expectations just skewed?

Can anyone see something that im doing wrong?

Note* Sql sits on an Azure VM with 4 cores and 8gb memory of which it gets 3gb

Note* I am now aware that I should not have called my column Level

**EDIT**

the following is from the EF6 Log

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[LogId] AS [LogId], 
    [Extent1].[ApplicationId] AS [ApplicationId], 
    [Extent1].[Type] AS [Type], 
    [Extent1].[Source] AS [Source], 
    [Extent1].[Message] AS [Message], 
    [Extent1].[LogTime] AS [LogTime], 
    [Extent1].[Level] AS [Level], 
    [Extent1].[Dat] AS [Dat]
    FROM [dbo].[Log] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[ApplicationId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Level] <= 3) AND ([Extent1].[Dat] IN (20160514,20160513))
-- p__linq__0: '2648' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
-- Executing at 5/14/2016 8:38:38 PM -04:00
-- Completed in 101 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

It would seem the query is quite fast. So why so slow to ToList()?

Comment: I doubt the query itself takes all that long. It's likely the enumeration for ToList that takes the most time.

Comment: Shouldn't `LazyLoadingEnabled` be set to `true`?  Depending on the nature of your related design of course

Comment: @TiesonT. How can i test that?

Comment: @MickyD That was a desperate chance, setting it either way doesnt seem to make a difference

Comment: The times you specify seem like typical times I get on my system.  The time running on SSMS is usually much quicker than a c# application.  With c# there is an extra layer of software that converts the results to xml format sends it to c# application and then converts back from xml to c# object.  The conversion and transfer time adds to the total time.

Comment: Is there anything strange in the columns like say blobs?

Comment: @Stilgar No nothing strange, only nvarchar or int

Comment: @jdweng What XML?  EF doesn't use XML by default and he hasn't yet begun returning the result it to the client via say WCF

Comment: use Linq to Entity and call .AsNoTracking() if you don't modify the data later and only want to query data. This speeds up calls a lot

Answer (score 2):

EF has to map the result of the SQL into an object, this may involve reflection and the dynamic loading of a mapper to turn the SQL result into a list of `logs`. If you're timing a single result, try executing the same thing within the same context a number of times. You will find that the per result execution time will decrease. This is because the mapper is already loaded and doesn't need to be retrieved.

I'm not an expert on EF, I just experimented with the same issue and found that the several seconds delay is only an issue for the first execution against the context.

Comment: This looks most likely to me. EF should run in comparable time to SSMS once it's 'warmed up'

Comment: Last time I did that in bulk, EF happily mapped half a million objects into a dictionary in half a second. Care to explain how this is supposedly different and so slow? -1, time  to learn how EF works.

Comment: @TomTom I suppose your test was performed in a different environment, under different circumstances, with different settings and possibly different EF versions from mine. The fact that your experience with EF is different doesn't make my experience invalid or my suggestion to test multiple queries against the same context wrong. Rather than trying to cut my answer down why not post your own and explain to the rest of us _how EF works_.

Comment: Not really. Unless you use totally outdated version of EF (which the OP does not say he uses and which would be comically old) and a mobile phone as database server, connecting it maybe over a 10 megabit network, it is relevant. Because that is the only way I can not see the answer as extremely bad. And you want to learn about the tools you use? EF is open source.

Comment: @TomTom So your answer is _"Read the code"_? Seems  less than productive. I'm sorry that my suggestion to the OP slighted you.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error I found I can cut the time it takes by at least half.

By first making a Count() call, I can then break the request into multiple pieces and request by page in small increments.

So the same 2213 items now takes 3-4 seconds by making two calls in parallel at only 1000 each. 10,000 items used to take 60 seconds, with this approach its ~18 seconds.

```
async Task<List<Log>> GeLogs(int count, int pageSize, string search)
{
    var pages = Math.Ceiling(count / s);

    var tasks = new Task<List<Log>>[(int)pages];
    for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++)
    {
        var page = i;
        tasks[i] = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var c = new DbEntities())
            {
                c.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                c.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

                var query = c.Logs.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Log WITH(NOLOCK) " + search + string.Format("ORDER BY LogTime DESC OFFSET (({0} - 1) * {1}) ROWS FETCH NEXT {1} ROWS ONLY", page + 1, (int)s));

                return query.ToList();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Going smaller than 1000 didnt seem to give better results.

Answer (score 0):

on sql management studio execute the same query

after the execution click on "show execution plan" button
[image]

read what is the problem in the report.
if needed execute the fix adding missing index..

Comment: I looked at this and also turned on Statistics, and I can see that my queries take less than half a second at the worst of times. I think the problem lies with EF i'm just not sure what to do about it.